# lwip raw api: tracking down double free in embedded systems and other possible issues

Tags: c, arm, lwip

I'm building a modbus tcp server on top of lwip, as the title says using the raw api since i'm using a bare metal system, as of today i have the application running, however when i poll too fast (lets say 1ms) the application crashes within 100 polls, if i lower the polling rate it still happens, just later on, in the serial debug i get

```
mem_free: illegal memory: non-linked: double freemem_free: illegal memory: non-linked: double free
```

the message is clear in what's happening, i'm having serious issues however tracking it down, i set a breakpoint where the message is produced and this is the call stack i get

```
>   mem_free (void * rmem) Line: 717    
pbuf_free (struct pbuf * p) Line: 780   
tcp_seg_free (struct tcp_seg * seg) Line: 1631  
tcp_segs_free (struct tcp_seg * seg) Line: 1616 
tcp_pcb_purge (struct tcp_pcb * pcb, struct tcp_pcb * pcb@entry) Line: 2169 
tcp_pcb_purge (struct tcp_pcb * pcb) Line: 2139 
tcp_pcb_remove (struct tcp_pcb ** pcblist, struct tcp_pcb * pcb, struct tcp_pcb * pcb@entry) Line: 2191 
tcp_input (struct pbuf * p, struct pbuf * p@entry, struct netif * inp, struct netif * inp@entry) Line: 448  
ip4_input (struct pbuf * p, struct pbuf * p@entry, struct netif * inp, struct netif * inp@entry) Line: 709  
ethernet_input (struct pbuf * p, struct netif * netif) Line: 186    
ethernetif_input (struct netif * netif) Line: 788   
ethernet_task Line: 247 
main Line: 929
```

Interestingly this seems to happen not on the application but on the ip layer when removing a pcb, i really don't know the lwip code good enough to adequately debug this

after the double free issue the interface stops responding

right now im using the following lwipopts

```
 * lwipopts.h
 *
 * Created: 11/10/2017 13:10:59
 *  Author: diego
 */

#define NO_SYS                1
#define LWIP_TIMERS             1
//#define NO_SYS_NO_TIMERS      1

#define MEM_ALIGNMENT 4
#define MEM_SIZE      (28*1024)

#define TCP_MSS  1460
#define TCP_SND_BUF (7*TCP_MSS)
#define TCP_WND     (7*TCP_MSS)
#define MEMP_NUM_TCP_SEG TCP_SND_QUEUELEN
#define MEMP_NUM_PBUF 16
#define MEMP_NUM_TCP_PCB 10

#define PBUF_POOL_SIZE 28

//Checksum handled by hardware
#define CHECKSUM_GEN_IP     0
#define CHECKSUM_GEN_UDP    0
#define CHECKSUM_GEN_TCP    0
#define CHECKSUM_GEN_ICMP   0
#define CHECKSUM_CHECK_IP   0
#define CHECKSUM_CHECK_UDP  0
#define CHECKSUM_CHECK_TCP  0
#define CHECKSUM_CHECK_ICMP 0


#define LWIP_DHCP                   1
#define LWIP_AUTOIP                 1
#define LWIP_DHCP_AUTOIP_COOP       1
#define LWIP_DHCP_AUTOIP_COOP_TRIES 5

#define LWIP_NETIF_HOSTNAME        1
#define LWIP_NETIF_API             0
#define LWIP_NETIF_STATUS_CALLBACK 1
#define LWIP_NETIF_LINK_CALLBACK   1

#define LWIP_SOCKET  0
#define LWIP_NETCONN 0

#define SO_REUSE     1
#define LWIP_IGMP    1

//#include <stmlib/rand.h>
//#define LWIP_RAND    rand_value

#define LWIP_STATS         1
#define LWIP_STATS_DISPLAY 1

extern int printf(const char *format, ...);
#define LWIP_PLATFORM_DIAG(x) {printf x;}
#define LWIP_DEBUG

#define LWIP_NOASSERT

#define LWIP_DBG_TYPES_ON               (LWIP_DBG_STATE | LWIP_DBG_ON)
#define ETHARP_DEBUG                    LWIP_DBG_OFF
#define NETIF_DEBUG                     LWIP_DBG_OFF
#define DHCP_DEBUG                      LWIP_DBG_OFF
#define AUTOIP_DEBUG                    LWIP_DBG_OFF
#define IGMP_DEBUG                      LWIP_DBG_OFF
#define IP_DEBUG                        LWIP_DBG_OFF
#define PBUF_DEBUG                      LWIP_DBG_LEVEL_SERIOUS
#define MEM_DEBUG                       LWIP_DBG_LEVEL_SERIOUS
#define SIMPLE_DISCOVERY_DEBUG          LWIP_DBG_LEVEL_SERIOUS

#define TCP_TMR_INTERVAL    10
```

the checksums are disabled since the phy already takes care of that

this is the .h of the lwip app

```
#define MODBUSTCP_H_

#include "lwip/debug.h"
#include "lwip/stats.h"
#include "lwip/tcp.h"
#include "../CONTROL_CONCURRENCIA/queue.h"
#include "../MEM_MGT/mempools.h"

#define MTCP_MAX_RETRIES        10
#define MTCP_QUEUE              modbusTcpQueue
#define MTCP_QUEUE_BUF          *mQueueBuffer[18]
#define MTCP_MEMP               modbusTcpMemp

#ifndef MTCP_MAX_CONNS
#define MTCP_MAX_CONNS  5
#endif

extern  queue_t MTCP_QUEUE;
extern  void    MTCP_QUEUE_BUF;
extern  mempool_config  MTCP_MEMP;

enum conn_status
{
    MB_NONE = 0,
    MB_CONNECTED,
    MB_WAIT_TO_CLOSE,
    MB_CLOSING
};

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t    transactionId;
    uint16_t    protocol;
    uint16_t    len;
    uint8_t     unitId;
} mbTcp_mbapHeader;

#define MBAP_PROTO_MB   0

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t estado;
    uint8_t retries;
    struct tcp_pcb *pcb;
    uint8_t *sendP;
    uint8_t sendLen;
} mbTcp_status;

void    modbusTcpStart(uint16_t port);
void    modbusTcpStop(void);

err_t   modbusTcpAccept(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *pcb, err_t err);

err_t   modbusTcpRecv(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *mPcb, struct pbuf *p, err_t err);
void    modbusTcpError(void *arg, err_t err);
err_t   modbusTcpPoll(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *mPcb);
void    modbusTcpSend(struct tcp_pcb *mPcb, mbTcp_status *mbStatus);
err_t   modbusTcpSent(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *pcb, u16_t len);
void    modbusTcpClose(struct tcp_pcb *pcb, mbTcp_status *mbStatus);

uint16_t    swapBytes(uint8_t *ptr);

extern  uint8_t mTcpCallGood(mbTcp_status *status, struct pbuf *p, mbTcp_mbapHeader hdr);
```

and this is the lwip app .cfile

```
/*
 * modbusTcp.c
 *
 * Created: 19/08/2019 14:05:11
 *  Author: diego
 */
#include "modbusTcp.h"

uint8_t actConns = 0;

uint16_t    swapBytes(uint8_t *ptr)
{
    uint16_t    out = ((uint16_t) * (ptr + 1)) | ((uint16_t) * (ptr) << 8);
    return out;
}

void    modbusTcpStart(uint16_t port)
{
    volatile err_t err;

    struct tcp_pcb *pcb;

    pcb = tcp_new();
    //LWIP_ASSERT("falla al crear el pcb de modbus tcp", pcb != NULL);

    if(pcb != NULL)
    {
        err = tcp_bind(pcb, IP_ADDR_ANY, port);
        //tcp_setprio(pcb, MODBUS_TCP_PRIO);
        //LWIP_ASSERT("Falla al iniciar modbus TCP (bind)", err == ERR_OK);

        if(err == ERR_OK)
        {
            pcb = tcp_listen(pcb);
            //LWIP_ASSERT("Falla al iniciar modbus TCP (listen)", err == ERR_OK);
            tcp_accept(pcb, modbusTcpAccept);
            return;
        }
    }
    else
        return;
}

err_t   modbusTcpAccept(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *mPcb, err_t err)
{
    err_t ret_err;
    mbTcp_status *mbStatus;

    LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(arg);
    LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(err);

    if(actConns >= MTCP_MAX_CONNS)
    {
        return ERR_MEM;
    }
    else
    {
        actConns++;
    }

    tcp_setprio(mPcb, TCP_PRIO_MAX);

    mbStatus = (mbTcp_status *)mem_malloc(sizeof(mbTcp_status));

    if(mbStatus != NULL)
    {
        mbStatus->estado = MB_CONNECTED;
        mbStatus->pcb = mPcb;
        mbStatus->retries = 0;
        mbStatus->sendP = NULL;
        /* pass newly allocated es to our callbacks */
        tcp_arg(mPcb, mbStatus);
        tcp_recv(mPcb, modbusTcpRecv);
        tcp_err(mPcb, modbusTcpError);
        tcp_poll(mPcb, modbusTcpPoll, 0);
        ret_err = ERR_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        ret_err = ERR_MEM;
    }

    return ret_err;
}


err_t   modbusTcpRecv(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *mPcb, struct pbuf *p, err_t err)
{

    mbTcp_status *mbStatus;
    volatile    mbTcp_mbapHeader    headerTmp;

    mbStatus = (mbTcp_status *)arg;
    uint8_t *payloadPtr     =   (uint8_t *) p->payload;

    //tcp_output(mPcb);

    if(p == NULL)
    {
        if(mbStatus->sendP == NULL)
        {
            if(getQueueLength(&MTCP_QUEUE) == 0)
            {
                // no quedan respuestas para mandar
                // ni bloques que procesar
                modbusTcpClose(mPcb, (mbTcp_status *)arg);
            }
            else
            {
                mbStatus->estado = MB_WAIT_TO_CLOSE;
                //pbuf_free(p);
            }

            // esto es que queda algo para procesar en la cola
            // la conexion se cerrara luego de que se procesen los que quedan
            // simplemente se descarta el entrante

        }
        else
        {
            // queda algo para mandar
            // asi que lo mandamos
            tcp_sent(mPcb, modbusTcpSent);
            //modbusTcpSend(mPcb, mbStatus);
        }
    }
    else
        if(err != ERR_OK)
        {
            mbStatus->sendP = NULL;
            tcp_recved(mPcb, p->tot_len);
            pbuf_free(p);
            return  err;
        }
        else
        {
            switch(mbStatus->estado)
            {
                case MB_CONNECTED:
                    if(p->len == 0)
                    {
                        tcp_recved(mPcb, p->tot_len);
                        pbuf_free(p);
                        break;
                    }

                    headerTmp.transactionId =   swapBytes(payloadPtr);
                    headerTmp.protocol      =   swapBytes(payloadPtr + 2);
                    headerTmp.len           =   swapBytes(payloadPtr + 4);
                    headerTmp.unitId        =   *(payloadPtr + 6);


                    if(mTcpCallGood(mbStatus, p, headerTmp) != 0)
                    {
                        if(p != NULL)
                        {
                            pbuf_free(p);
                        }

                        tcp_recved(mPcb, p->tot_len);
                        break;
                    }

                    // asumimos que los chequeos y demas fueron realizados por el stack

                    break;

                case MB_WAIT_TO_CLOSE:
                    // notese que no ponemos mbStatus->p a NULL
                    tcp_recved(mPcb, p->tot_len);
                    pbuf_free(p);
                    return ERR_OK;
                    break;

                case MB_CLOSING:
                    tcp_recved(mPcb, p->tot_len);
                    mbStatus->sendP = NULL;
                    pbuf_free(p);
                    return ERR_OK;
                    break;

                default:
                    tcp_recved(mPcb, p->tot_len);
                    mbStatus->sendP = NULL;
                    pbuf_free(p);
                    return ERR_OK;
                    break;
            }
        }
}

void    modbusTcpError(void *arg, err_t err)
{
    mbTcp_status *mbStatus;

    LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(err);

    mbStatus = (mbTcp_status *)arg;



    tcp_arg(mbStatus->pcb, NULL);
    tcp_sent(mbStatus->pcb, NULL);
    tcp_recv(mbStatus->pcb, NULL);
    tcp_err(mbStatus->pcb, NULL);
    tcp_poll(mbStatus->pcb, NULL, 0);
    tcp_close(mbStatus->pcb);

    /*if(mbStatus != NULL)
    {
        mem_free(mbStatus);
    }*/
}

void    modbusTcpSend(struct tcp_pcb *mPcb, mbTcp_status *mbStatus)
{
    err_t wr_err = ERR_OK;

    while((wr_err == ERR_OK) &&
            (mbStatus->sendP != NULL) &&
            (mbStatus->sendLen <= tcp_sndbuf(mPcb))
         )
    {
        wr_err = tcp_write(mPcb, mbStatus->sendP, mbStatus->sendLen, 1);

        if(wr_err == ERR_OK)
        {
            mbStatus->sendLen = 0;
            break;
        }
        else
            if(wr_err == ERR_MEM)
            {
                // por ahora simplemente no mandamos nada
                // idealmente seria defer to poll
            }
    }

    return;
}

err_t   modbusTcpPoll(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *mPcb)
{

}

void    modbusTcpClose(struct tcp_pcb *mPcb, mbTcp_status *mbStatus)
{
    tcp_arg(mPcb, NULL);
    tcp_sent(mPcb, NULL);
    tcp_recv(mPcb, NULL);
    tcp_err(mPcb, NULL);
    tcp_poll(mPcb, NULL, 0);

    if(mbStatus != NULL)
    {
        mem_free(mbStatus);
    }

    tcp_close(mPcb);
    actConns--;
}

err_t   modbusTcpSent(void *arg, struct tcp_pcb *mPcb, u16_t len)
{
    mbTcp_status *mbStatus;

    mbStatus = (mbTcp_status *)arg;

    LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(len);

    mbStatus->retries = 0;

    if(mbStatus->estado == MB_WAIT_TO_CLOSE)
    {
        if(getQueueLength(&MTCP_QUEUE) == 0)
        {
            // no quedan respuestas para mandar
            // ni bloques que procesar
            modbusTcpClose(mPcb, (mbTcp_status *)arg);
        }
    }

    // no quedan respuestas para mandar
    // y ya no habia nada en la cola
    if(mbStatus->estado == MB_CLOSING)
    {
        modbusTcpClose(mPcb, mbStatus);
    }

    return ERR_OK;
}
```

this is the code that actually handles the queued packets

```
#include "lwip/stats.h"
#include "lwip/tcp.h"
#include "lwip/pbuf.h"

#define MBTCP_CALL_GOOD mTcpCallGood
#include "modbusTcp.h"


void    initModbusTcpBalanza(void);
void    modbusTcpParser(void);


extern          MB_DBlock_t modbusDataBlock;
queue_t         modbusTcpQueue;
mempool_config  modbusTcpMemp;
void            *mQueueBuffer[18];

uint8_t         packet_buffer[260];

typedef struct
{
    struct pbuf         *p;
    mbTcp_mbapHeader    header;
    MB_pdu              pdu;
    mbTcp_status        *connStat;
} modbusTcpQueueElement;

#define MBTCP_POOL_SZ   (sizeof(modbusTcpQueueElement)+36)*18
uint8_t mbTcpPoolBuffer[MBTCP_POOL_SZ];

uint8_t mTcpCallGood(mbTcp_status *status, struct pbuf *p, mbTcp_mbapHeader hdr)
{
    modbusTcpQueueElement   *queueElement;

    if(hdr.len > 253)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else
        if(pool_allocate(&modbusTcpMemp, (uint8_t **)&queueElement) != 0)
        {
            queueElement->header        = hdr;
            queueElement->p             = p;
            queueElement->pdu.pduData   = (uint8_t *) & (p->payload[7]);
            queueElement->pdu.dataLen   = hdr.len - 1;
            queueElement->connStat      = status;

            if(enQueue(&modbusTcpQueue, queueElement) == -1)
            {
                while(true);
            }

            return 0;
        }
        else
            return 1;
}

void    modbusTcpParser(void)
{
    //Disable_global_interrupt();

    struct pbuf *p;
    uint8_t parseRet;

    if(getQueueLength(&modbusTcpQueue) > 0)
    {
        modbusTcpQueueElement *queueElement;

        queueGetNext(&modbusTcpQueue, (void **)&queueElement);
        uint8_t *mbapPtr = (uint8_t *) & (queueElement->header);
        //delay_ms(1);

        // copiamos a un buffer que sabemos tiene lugar
        for(uint8_t i = 0; i < queueElement->pdu.dataLen; i++)
        {
            packet_buffer[i + 7] =  queueElement->pdu.pduData[i];
        }

        tcp_recved(queueElement->connStat->pcb, queueElement->p->tot_len);
        pbuf_free(queueElement->p);

        queueElement->pdu.pduData = &packet_buffer[7];

        switch(parseRet = parseModbusPdu(&(queueElement->pdu), modbusDataBlock))
        {
            case ERRCODE_PARSE_FAIL_NR:
                break;

            case ERRCODE_PARSE_OK:
            case ERRCODE_ILL_DATA_ADDR:
            case ERRCODE_ILL_FUNCTION:
                queueElement->header.len = queueElement->pdu.dataLen;

                packet_buffer[0] = mbapPtr[1];
                packet_buffer[1] = mbapPtr[0];
                packet_buffer[2] = mbapPtr[3];
                packet_buffer[3] = mbapPtr[2];
                packet_buffer[4] = mbapPtr[5];
                packet_buffer[5] = mbapPtr[4];
                packet_buffer[6] = mbapPtr[6];

                queueElement->connStat->sendP   = packet_buffer;
                queueElement->connStat->sendLen = 7 + queueElement->pdu.dataLen;

                modbusTcpSend(queueElement->connStat->pcb, queueElement->connStat);

                //mb_232_resp(queueElement->port, queueElement->pdu.dataLen);
                break;

            default:
                tcp_recved(queueElement->connStat->pcb, queueElement->p->tot_len);
                pbuf_free(queueElement->p);
                break;
        }

        // ojo, bloquear las interrupciones aca es muy importante
        // llegaba a pasar que eliminaba de la cola pero no liberaba el elemento
        Disable_global_interrupt();
        pool_free(&modbusTcpMemp, (uint8_t *)queueElement);
        deQueue(&modbusTcpQueue);
        Enable_global_interrupt();
    }

    //Enable_global_interrupt();
    return;
}

void    initModbusTcp(void)
{
    init_pool(&modbusTcpMemp, MBTCP_POOL_SZ, sizeof(modbusTcpQueueElement) + 36, mbTcpPoolBuffer);
    queue_init((void **)mQueueBuffer, 18, &modbusTcpQueue);
}
```

Any help or leads are very appreciated

Pd: I know this code needs a lot of improvements and formatting, yet this is my first lwip app, and i need to get to a reasonable operating level relatively fast, so tidyness and order will be left for a bit later

Comment: Whelp, are you seriously expecting anyone to debug all that code for you? You should create a [**minimal** reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: im not expecting for someone to debug all this for me, just asking if anyone with a lot of experience with lwip sees something obvious that im not seeing, possibly in the lwipopts part

Comment: In my book finding a bug == debugging, but ok. Just saying that this is not the typical question that makes people want to answer it. In fact, it could be even interpreted as being off topic as per the rule: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.".

Comment: finding a bug == debugging but not necessarily in depth debugging, and the thing is that this happens somewhat at random, hadn't been able yet to produce a mre

Comment: regarding: `if(p != NULL)
                        {
                            pbuf_free(p);
                        }

                        tcp_recved(mPcb, p->tot_len);`   should not be accessing anything that is pointed to by `p` after `p` has been passed to `pBuf_free()`.  However, if `p` contains NULL, then should still not be accessing anything (in this case memory address 0) pointed to by `p`

Comment: The "double free" may not actually be a "double free".  If you free a block and then use it, the allocator list of free blocks can be corrupt.  It may then think that some unrelated block is free.  For instance dlmalloc with inline allocator block can have this happen.  See [some graphics here](https://blog.nsogroup.com/a-tale-of-two-mallocs-on-android-libc-allocators-part-1-dlmalloc/).  Can you compile and run the code on a PC?  There is 'dmalloc' to add debug tracing of allocation; but it may not work (well) on your system.